# Replace icon on checkout page for WooCommerce PayPal Checkout Gateway Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, hook-woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce's "WooCommerce PayPal Checkout Gateway" plugin and I would like to use a custom image for where it display in the payment options section on the checkout page.

I have tried the below but neither work; I figure they may be for the default PayPal implementation they have without using a plugin?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_icon', 'my_replace_paypal_icon', 99 );

function my_replace_paypal_icon() {
    return 'https://your_image_url';
}
```

..and...

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gateway_icon', 'my_paypal_gateway_icon', 10, 2 );

function paypal_gateway_icon( $icon, $id ) {
    if ( $id === 'paypal' ) {
        return '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/woocommerce-icons/cards.png" alt="Authorize.net" />';
    } else {
        return $icon;
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Woocommerce default Paypal payment gateway, you will use exclusively the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_icon', 'custom_paypal_icon', 10, 2 );
function custom_paypal_icon( $icon ) {
    return '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/woocommerce-icons/cards.png" alt="Paypal" />';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

For the plugin [WooCommerce PayPal Checkout Payment Gateway](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/), try this *(the correct payment method Id is `ppec_paypal`)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gateway_icon', 'custom_payment_gateway_icons', 10, 2 );
function custom_payment_gateway_icons( $icon, $gateway_id ){
    // For Paypal Checkout (or Paypal Express) only
    if( $gateway_id == 'ppec_paypal' ) {
        $icon = '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/woocommerce-icons/cards.png" alt="Paypal Express" />';
    }
    return $icon;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Where do you find the proper id's? As I need to do something similar for their Stripe gateway as well.

Comment: @Brett In backend, on Settings > Payments, when you click on a payment method, you can see after in the URL: `?page=wc-settings&tab=checkout&section=ppec_paypal`, where `ppec_paypal` change for each payment method. Or you can inspect the links on main payment page. Also in Frontend checkout, if you inspect the payment radio buttons, you can also get the ID for each.

Comment: Excellent - thanks again. Before I read your comment I also found you can see it in the inspector for the `label`; such as: `payment_method_*`.

Comment: @Brett Or simply the "value" of each input radio button